# cavity.OpenFOAM file empty, what to do?

Tags: mesh, paraview, openfoam

I'm trying to learn how to use OpenFOAM. To do so, I'm working my way through the cavity example, found here:

https://cfd.direct/openfoam/user-guide/v8-cavity/

In step [2.1.2 Viewing the mesh](https://cfd.direct/openfoam/user-guide/v8-cavity/#x5-110002.1.2) I run paraFoam and a window opens called *ParaView 5.6.0 64-bit*. The render view of the window is empty (see screenshot). I expect to see a mesh here, as shown in the tutorial. I cannot select a coloring in the window, because the Display tab is empty, even when I click the little cog wheel at the top of the tabs.

**I found that the file `cavity.OpenFOAM`, which is generated by `paraFoam`, is empty, i.e. it has zero bytes.**

[image]

```
$ icoFoam -help
[...]
Using: OpenFOAM-7 (see https://openfoam.org)
Build: 7-1ff648926f77
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cavity.OpenFOAM is always a 0 byte file.

- In ParaView make sure to select the required Mesh Parts before you hit apply.
  [select Mesh Parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jou6z.png)'
- After hitting apply, change the view from 'Surface' to 'Surface With Edges
  [Surface With Edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7EQH.png)

Comment: The "eye" is closed, just open it, then you can see a gray surface.